# How can I make a call, as I recieve a push notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, appointment

I have developed an appointment application. When I receive a push notification, I want to make a call to a particular person, but right now it is just opening the application when I get a push notification.

How do I write a code to make a call to a particular appointment as I get the push notification of that appointment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon notification, open the dialer app with the given phone number. Note: this will initially launch your app, then quickly switch to the dialer.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://5555555555"]];
}
```

Comment: I think i answer the same thing?

Comment: Ah, yes. Didn't get the notification that other answers had been added :/ +1 for the answer by KingOfBliss

Comment: Hmmm.. If so, +1 for your ans too. :)

Comment: Thanks :) I should probably get in the habit of refreshing the page before submitting an answer I suppose

Answer (score 3):

For push notification you have to code in appDelegate,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[userInfo valueForKey:@"phno"]]]];
}
```

For local notification,

```
    -(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
    {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"phno"]]]];
    }
```